# Decorate api requests with Bearer token in NextJS getServerSideProps

Tags: session, jwt, next.js, auth0

I am using `axios` interceptors to decorate all my requests with an `Authorization` header.

I get the token from `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` by using an API route `/api/token`:

```
import auth0 from '@/libs/auth0/auth0';
import { AccessTokenResponse } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/dist/tokens/token-cache';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export async function getAccessToken(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<AccessTokenResponse> {
  const tokenCache = auth0(req).tokenCache(req, res);
  return tokenCache.getAccessToken();
}

export default async function token(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res);
    res.status(200).end(accessToken);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
  }
}
```

The api route works fine on the client side requests and I can see the token being added and requests going through.

```
const { token } = await axios.get('/api/token');

    const result = {
      ...config,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${data}`,
      },
    };
    return result;
```

However this does not work for the SSR pages when I use the same `axios` interceptors.

I tried full qualifying the url like so:

```
const { token } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/token');
```

But this throws an error in the SSR layer:

```
The user does not have a valid session.
```

I do not know how to get the token from the token cache to be used in the interceptor for the api calls made via SSR?

Any ideas or similar experience?

Comment: Can you share the full code in your API route?

Comment: Have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I opted to store the token as a cookie for all requests and access it through the req key in the context parameter when using SSR:

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req }) {
    const accessToken = req.cookies.token

    // Remaining code
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props